# 3D printing support for desktop apps in Windows 10

Tags: c#, 3d, windows-runtime

I would like to integrate 3D printing support into my C#.NET desktop app. According to this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/bg183398.aspx it should be natively supported in Windows 10. However, the only example and APIs seems to be for Windows Store Apps (WinRT), not desktop apps. Any idea how can I achieve this? Or how can I use this C++ WinRT dll in C#.Net desktop app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the SDK then you can use the API :) .

SDK : http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=394375

**UPDATE :**

Sorry, I think that it's supported in the new desktop apps -need extension- not the classic WPF, WinForm desktop apps !

**UPDATE 2 :**

The API is for the desktop device family, which mean that you've to use it along with the Desktop Extension..

Ref : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn706136.aspx

Comment: Sorry, but how can I "include" SDK?